# What is the best way to drop last element using c++20 ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

Is there any better way to drop last element in container using c++20 ranges than reverse it twice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    for (const auto& d: foo | std::ranges::views::reverse 
                            | std::ranges::views::drop(1) 
                            | std::ranges::views::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you *required* to use ranges? What are your exact requirements and limitations?

Comment: What about `take` ? What about just a loop from `begin` to `end-1` excluded ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I'm not required to use std::ranges. I was just thinking about how can I use these adaptors in real-world example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is `views::drop_last` which comes from [p2214](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html) and has a priority of Tier 2.

As the [paper says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html#the-takedrop-family):

> We’ll go through the other potential range adapters in this family and
> discuss how they could be implemented in terms of existing adapters:
>
> - `take_last(N)` and `drop_last(N)`. `views::take_last(N)` is equivalent to
>   `views::reverse | views::take(N) | views::reverse`. But this is somewhat
>   expensive, especially for non-common views. For random-access, sized
>   ranges, we’re probably want `r | views::take_last(N)` to evaluate as `r | views::drop(r.size() - N)`, and that desire is really the crux of this
>   whole question — is the equivalent version good enough or should we
>   want to do it right?

Since `vector` is a random-access, sized range, you can just do

```
for (const auto& d: foo | std::views::take(foo.size() - 1))
{
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

How about using `span`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> foo{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

  for (const auto& d : std::span(foo.begin(), foo.end() - 1)) {
    std::cout << d << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution too. I wanted to get rid of iterators and use only range adaptors.

Comment: @cr0pp I see. This is an exceptionally good use case for `std::span`, though. That's exactly what it's designed to do.

Comment: You can spell this: `std::span(foo).first(foo.size() - 1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do a good approximation via:

```cpp
struct drop_last_t {
    template <std::ranges::sized_range R>
        requires std::ranges::viewable_range<R>
    friend auto operator|(R&& r, drop_last_t) {
        auto n = std::ranges::size(r);
        return std::views::take(std::forward<R>(r), n > 0 ? n - 1 : 0);
    }
};
inline constexpr drop_last_t drop_last;
```

That [lets you](https://godbolt.org/z/ePrv74rv9):

```cpp
for (const auto& d: foo | drop_last)
```

This isn't a perfect range adaptor, since you can't write something like `auto my_adaptor = transform(f) | drop_last;` In order to do that, you need [P2387](https://wg21.link/p2387), which is a C++23 library feature. In C++23, you'd write it this way:

```cpp
struct drop_last_t : std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure<drop_last_t>
{
    template <std::ranges::sized_range R>
        requires std::ranges::viewable_range<R>
    auto operator()(R&& r) const {
        auto n = std::ranges::size(r);
        return std::views::take(std::forward<R>(r), n > 0 ? n - 1 : 0);
    }
};
inline constexpr drop_last_t drop_last;
```

And now this is a completely functional range adaptor. The current libstdc++-specific version looks [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/M5obaM3qG) (just to demonstrate, don't actually do this - this isn't how you'd do this in C++23).

---

Of course, this is limited to sized ranges. There's all sorts of directions this could go. You could support any forward range by doing `std::ranges::distance(r)` instead (at the cost of multiple traversal). But a bespoke implementation could do better. For bidi+common, you just need to stop at `prev(end(r))`. For forward only, you could advance two iterators at a time, etc. Just something to think about.

Comment: Thanks for your addition, Barry. But should this `drop_last` name `head` as p2214 does? Since it's more like `drop_last(1)`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Shrug. I'm not sure which is the better name.

Comment: question regarding requires:  can a "reasonable"(not intentionally broken to pass concept check)  range be sized_range, but not viewable_range? Seems impossible, but maybe I am missing something...

Comment: "*can a "reasonable"(not intentionally broken to pass concept check) range be sized_range, but not viewable_range?*" Are there any dependencies between these two concepts? Why is it not possible? Isn't `std::initializer_list<int>` just one?

Comment: @康桓瑋 ah yes, did not think of that, I presume you mean something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/qzsqj86xe (nice error message from gcc btw )

Comment: There's nothing special about the error message, it's just that range `operator|` is not a valid expression since the constraints are not satisfied, so the compiler is just trying to use `operator|` defined elsewhere in the standard library.