# Workaround to decrement iterator from views::transform?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string_view foo = "This is a test";
    
    auto split_foo = foo |
                        std::views::split(' ') |
                        std::ranges::views::transform( 
                            []( const auto &word )
                            {
                                return std::string_view{std::begin(word),std::end(word)};
                            } );

    auto it = std::begin(split_foo);
    while (it != std::end(split_foo))
    {
        std::cout<< "-> " << *it <<std::endl;
        it = std::next(it);
    }
}
```

That produces the following output:

```
-> This
-> is
-> a
-> test
```

I would like to iterate until one-before-end, such that the output is:

```
-> This
-> is
-> a
```

According to the following reference from [std::ranges::prev](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/prev)

> ... for some underlying ranges, ranges::transform_view::end doesn't have the same return type as ranges::transform_view::begin, and so --r.end() won't compile. This isn't something that ranges::prev can aid with, **but there are workarounds**.

Does anyone know a workaround to decrement the end iterator from `std::ranges::views::transform`?

ps. I have tried `std::next(std::end(split_foo), -1)`, which compiles but crashes the program because the iterator is not bidirectional.

Comment: Why don't you drop the last element before transform?

Comment: @Eugene: I could do! It's a nice suggestion.

Comment: You may consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689137/what-is-the-best-way-to-drop-last-element-using-c20-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `while`-loop to:

```
auto it = split_foo.begin();
auto next = std::ranges::next(it);
while (next != split_foo.end()) {
  std::cout<< "-> " << *it <<std::endl;
  it = next;
  next = std::ranges::next(next);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ncEnnEf9z)

Do not use `std::xxx` to operate iterators when dealing with C++20 `<ranges>`, instead, you should use `ranges::xxx`, since the former is not compatible with the C++20 iterator system.

Comment: This feels like it does extra work calling `next` twice per loop. You should probably factor this out into an `if` and a `do{}while()` to avoid it.

Comment: nice and neat, thanks! I am interested to know more about `the former is not compatible with the C++20 iterator system`. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos For example, [some C++20 random access iterators are just input iterators in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606563/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-category-and-iterator-concept-in-c20), so you can't apply `std::prev` to it but you can decrement it with `ranges::prev`.

Comment: @康桓瑋: Lovely! +1 for the question and +1 to the answer.